# Connection between API and Service with MediatR

Tags: c#, service, mediatr

In Ubuntu operating system, I have two services that I wrote in asp.net core, C#:

1. API (with client side in react), (run by apache2)
2. Monitor service (run like a service in /etc/systemd/system/monitor)

I would like that when the user logs in, the API will update the monitor that the user has logged in.

I wrote it and it doesn't work for me:

In shared project (class projects):

```
public class Ping : INotification { }
```

in API - in the controller:

```
await _mediator.Publish(new Ping());
```

in API - in the program.cs:

```
 builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg =>

            {

                cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(AuthController).Assembly);

            });
```

in service - in worker.cs:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService, INotificationHandler<Ping>
{
  public Task Handle(Ping notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

    {
        _logger.Info("inside Handle Ping");
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    } 
}
```

in service - in program.cs:

```
 services.AddMediatR(cfg =>

        {

            cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Worker).Assembly);

        });
```

and it's still not working.
It's publish the ping, but the service not get it or not recognise it.